# File Not Found on python for importing a csv. The file path is correct and everything is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, import, file-not-found

I have installed pandas and have been trying to figure this out for a few days. The file path is correct and I even tried copy/pasting the file path. I'm working on Jupyter Notebook through Anaconda on a Mac (not sure if that makes a difference. I've attached the code here:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2e4763966abb> in <module>
----> 1 df1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/snerbs/Desktop/PYTHON/Testing_Statistical_Hypotheses/Section2/Goats50.csv")

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    446 
    447     # Create the parser.
--> 448     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    449 
    450     if chunksize or iterator:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    878             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    879 
--> 880         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    881 
    882     def close(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1112     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1113         if engine == "c":
-> 1114             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1115         else:
   1116             if engine == "python":

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1889         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1890 
-> 1891         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1892         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1893 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C:/Users/snerbs/Desktop/PYTHON/Testing_Statistical_Hypotheses/Section2/Goats50.csv does not exist: 'C:/Users/snerbs/Desktop/PYTHON/Testing_Statistical_Hypotheses/Section2/Goats50.csv'
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the path is correct? Check if the file is where you think it is by running the following on a notebook cell.

```
!ls path_to_folder_with_csv
```

The output should contain your file. Also, you should post the code, not links to pictures.

Comment: You were correct! I using C drive but my computer doesn't have one. That is a great trick, thank you for attaching that code!

Comment: You are welcome! You can execute any shell command using the `!command` syntax in jupyter notebook. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved the problem.